# local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: sql, laravel, querybuilder

Buen día, he tratado de hacer una consulta de MySQL en Query builder pero se me ha complicado mucho, de antemano agradezco a cualquiera que me pueda ayudar

la consulta trata de hacer un Join con 4 tablas ademas de traer las tuplas del id que se encuentre repetido.

Aqui el Query funcional que me retorna los datos necesarios

```
SELECT e.id_item,e.estado,e.descripcion,i.nombre_item , s.nombre_sub, c.nombre_cat
FROM estados e, items i, subcategorias s, categorias c 
WHERE (e.id_item = i.id and i.id_subcategoria = s.id and c.id = s.id_categoria)
AND e.id_item IN (
SELECT id_item
FROM estados
GROUP BY id_item
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY id_item
```

Y esto es lo que he estado intentando hacer en query builder y que me retorna error 500:

```
$reincidencia = DB::table('estados')
        ->join ('items','items.id','=','estados.id_item')
        ->join ('subcategorias','items.id_subcategoria','=','subcategorias.id')
        ->join ('categorias', 'subcategorias.id_categoria','=','categorias.id')
        ->select('estados.id_item','estados.descripcion','items.nombre_item','items.serial','items.estado','items.ubicacion','subcategorias.nombre_sub','categorias.nombre_cat',
                    DB::raw("(WHERE id_item and IN (
                        SELECT id_item
                        FROM estados
                        GROUP BY id_item
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"))
        ->orderBy('items.id_item')
        ->get();
```

Trate de hacer otro intento con query builder aunque me sigue dando error:

```
$reincidencia = DB::table('estados')
        ->join ('items','items.id','=','estados.id_item')
        ->join ('subcategorias','items.id_subcategoria','=','subcategorias.id')
        ->join ('categorias', 'subcategorias.id_categoria','=','categorias.id')
        ->select('estados.id_item','estados.descripcion','items.nombre_item','items.serial','items.estado','items.ubicacion','subcategorias.nombre_sub','categorias.nombre_cat')
        ->whereIn('id_item', DB::raw("SELECT id_item FROM estados GROUP BY id_item HAVING COUNT(*)>1"))            
        ->orderBy('estados.id_item')
        ->get();
```

error que me retorna:

```
app.js:412 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/reporte3 500 (Internal Server Error)
app.js:826 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:826)
    at settle (app.js:1087)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:295)
```

Logs de error:

```
[2020-10-03 00:24:59] local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Users\Deneros\Desktop\IOApp\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 919 {"userId":6,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php on line 919 at C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php:3078)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(919): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->cleanBindings(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression))
#1 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\app\\Http\\Controllers\
eportesController.php(30): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->whereIn('id_item', Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression))
#2 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\
eportesController->reincidencia()
#3 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('reincidencia', Array)
#5 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(239): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\
eportesController), 'reincidencia')
#6 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(196): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#7 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#8 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(77): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(687): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(628): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#26 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(617): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.5 prueba pdf\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\Denero...')
#46 {main}
"}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál el el problema con esa consulta?, ¿no sirve o qué es lo que retorna?

Comment: En el codigo de query builder simplemente me da un error y no retorna nada

Comment: agrega ese error

Comment: Ya lo agregue, gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: agrega un dd($reincidencia) para ver que te sale

Comment: ese error es del servidor, revisa el log de laravel  y agregalo aqui

Comment: Ya agregue el log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya me dio los resultados que quería, en el primer intento hice una mala estructuración del DB::raw

Y del segundo intento solo me faltaba [ ] dentro del whereIn, quedaria de esta forma

```
$reincidencia = DB::table('estados')
        ->join ('items','items.id','=','estados.id_item')
        ->join ('subcategorias','items.id_subcategoria','=','subcategorias.id')
        ->join ('categorias', 'subcategorias.id_categoria','=','categorias.id')
        ->select('estados.id_item','estados.descripcion','items.nombre_item','items.serial','items.estado','items.ubicacion','subcategorias.nombre_sub','categorias.nombre_cat')
        ->whereIn('estados.id_item', [DB::raw("SELECT id_item FROM estados GROUP BY id_item HAVING COUNT(*)>1")])            
        ->orderBy('estados.id_item')
        ->get();
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada, por eso te recomiendo siempre mira el log de errores

Comment: Vale, te lo agradezco mucho.